# if..else warning " not all control paths return a value"

Tags: c++, loops, return, warnings

I have an if...else statement and am getting the warning " not all control paths return a value" when I compile.  Can anyone tell me why I am getting this warning?

My code:

```
template<typename T>                                                                        
double NumericArray<T>::Dot(const NumericArray& na)
{
    if (Size() == na.Size())
    {
        double result = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<Size(); i++)
        {
            result += ((na.GetElement(i))*(GetElement(i)));
        }
        return result;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout<<"Error! Dot Product Operands Number Of Elements Unequal"<<endl;
    }
}
```

I don't see how anything other than the defined results can be reached through my code.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider: what value does this function return when `Size()` is not equal to `na.Size()`?

Comment: @Byron You should consider John Kugelman answer,for your approach you might not want to return anything but throw an exception in that else with that message and manage it in some other level.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because there is no return statement in your final else or outside the if block.

If this condition `if (Size() == na.Size())` evaluates to false the method doesn't return a value.

Answer (score 4):

There's neither a `return` statement nor a `throw` inside the `else` clause.

Comment: Agree. The `else` case seems like it should have read `throw std::domain_error("Dot Product Operands Number Of Elements Unequal")`. Even if you'd print such a message, it should go to `std::cerr` instead of `std::cout`.